Sublime Text RegReplace, modify increment Date/Time to insert current Date/Time
I do created a custom Sublime Text RegReplace rule that can modify my G-code files and adapt them to my needs, the only missing piece of code is a way to insert the current Date/Time when I am running RegReplace command.
I did my research, and looks like RegReplace have support for custom plugins, there it is even a sample plugin that does increment all the dates found in document.
Custom Replace Plugins
I do need something similar, but instead to search my documents for dates and increment them I do need to find a piece of text in document, like "InsertDateTimeHere" and replace-it with the current Date/Time, like: " 2024.10.17 13:20:35 ".
If somebody know how this can be achieved, please help.
I took some inspiration from this plugin: Insert DateTime Sublime Text Notepad F5 but I don't know how I can make the code to work with RegReplace, as seems that RegReplace plugin needs to have a replace function that can return something like time.strftime( ' %Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S ' )

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
